# integrating Sherlock ActionBar-Build Using Gradle

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I have just integrated SherlockActionBar in my android project but I am getting many `Error:(1) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined` errors when trying to build. The error refers me to `colors.xml` which is straight forward:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blueDark">#2C3E50</color>
    <color name="blueLight">#00BD9C</color>
    <color name="white">#F9F9F9</color>
    <color name="themeOrange">#FF8040</color>
    <color name="themeGray">#ff8A9199</color>
    <color name="themeLightGray">#ffeaeaea</color>
    <color name="themeDarkGray">#ff3f434b</color>
    <color name="themeRed">#ffCC292B</color>
    <color name="themeBlue">#ff002E63</color>
    <color name="themeWhite">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="buttonNormal">@color/themeGray</color>
    <color name="buttonPressed">@color/themeBlue</color>
</resources>
```

Also I got stuff like `Can't resolve symbol R` or the `getActivity()` method when using with fragments.
Here is my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7.2'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

}

I am working with package 22 so I didn't change it to 18 like what the documentation suggests, is this fine?

Comment: ActionBarSherlock was marked as deprecated by its author (Jake Wharton) about two years ago. It should only be used by existing apps (that pre-dated the deprecation), not new apps. Whether you use the native action bar or `appcompat-v7` for your action bar is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the appcompat and the actionbarsherlock together. These libraries define the same attrs.

Use the AppCompat Library, it is enough.

Comment: Would you refer me to a good reference on how to use AppCompat Library?

Comment: You can start from official blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Then here: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Answer (score 1):

ActionbarSherlock is no longer supported. There is now an official Google solution in the AppCompat Library. You should use that instead.